# Firebase CLI gives an error when creating new firebase project in flutter (Failed to create project because there is already a project with ID proj-id

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-tools

I want to link my Flutter project to a Firebase project.

I use Firebase CLI to create a new Firebase project. When I choose `<create a new project>` option, it gives the message that the project is created successfully, as you can see below, but also gives me an error that a project with the same ID already exists.

When I go to the Firebase console, there is no project by the same ID (not existed before and is not created now!).

```
✔ Select a Firebase project to configure your Flutter application with · <create a new project>
✔ Enter a project id for your new Firebase project (e.g. my-cool-project) · my-random-project
i New Firebase project my-random-project created successfully.
FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase projects:create my-random-project --json 
ERROR: Failed to create project because there is already a project with ID my-random-project. Please try again with a unique project ID.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Project IDs are shared across all users, so somebody else already used `my-cool-project` as the ID for their project. You'll need to specify a project ID that is globally unique across all users.

If you're finding it hard to come up with such a globally unique project ID  yourself, I recommend creating a project in the Firebase or Cloud console - as both of those suggest a project ID when you've entered a duplicate.